# Symfony3: How to set multiple connections?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping, symfony

I'm working with a Symfony3 app and I want to set up multiple connections to different databases.

I've been looking around and I found out the documentation about entityManagers and DB connections. My config.yml is configured as follows:

config.yml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
            default:
                    driver:   pdo_mysql
                    host:     "%database_host%"
                    port:     "%database_port%"
                    dbname:   "%database_name%"
                    user:     "%database_user%"
                    password: "%database_password%"
                    charset:  UTF8
                    mapping_types:
                      enum: string
            other:
                    driver:   pdo_mysql
                    host:     "%database_host2%"
                    port:     "%database_port2%"
                    dbname:   "%database_name2%"
                    user:     "%database_user2%"
                    password: "%database_password2%"
                    charset:  UTF8
                    mapping_types:
                      enum: string
orm:
    dql:
         string_functions:
                DAY:   DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
                MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                YEAR:  DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
```

So now I do can access to my database like this:

```
$con2 = $this->get('doctrine.dbal.other_connection');
$orders = $con2->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM orders');
```

But what I really need is to configure a second orm-mapping connection which will allow me to interact with entities instead of dealing with the second database directly. So again as the documentation says I added under the doctrine orm label:

```
orm:
    dql:
         string_functions:
                DAY:   DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
                MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                YEAR:  DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true

    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                AppBundle:  ~      
        other:
            connection: other
            mappings:
                OtherBundle: ~
```

This throws an exception:

> ParseException in Parser.php line 296:
>   Unable to parse at line 78 (near " entity_managers:").

How should I configure my config.yml to allow orm-mapping for my second database connection? Should I delete the dql label and use it only under a certain entity manager label?

Comment: The error is related to a YAML syntax error. However, this is not reflected by the example config you are showing here. You may want to show your complete config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    AppBundle: ~
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                dql:
                   string_functions:
                       DAY: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
            other:
                mappings:
                    OtherBundle: ~
```

Answer (score 3):

check the [doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) for full reference of the configuration about doctrine.

Check the indentation of the dql function etc.

Probably us are using the [Shortened Configuration Syntax](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#shortened-configuration-syntax) where all options available can be placed directly under doctrine.orm config level.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Thanks for the answers because they were pretty much the solution. I just had to use the labels in their correct levels.

Just in case it can be useful for someone, I'll post what I've done:

config.yml

```
 orm:

    entity_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                AppBundle: ~
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping: true
            dql:
                         string_functions:
                                DAY:   DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
                                MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                                YEAR:  DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
        other:
            mappings:
                OtherBundle: ~
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore

    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
```

Once the (other) entity manager is created you just can use it within a controller as you'd do with the default em just by specifying the entity manager name you are using.

```
$orders = $this->get('doctrine')
        ->getRepository('OtherBundle:Orders', 'other')
        ->findAll();
```

Now you're ready to go.

Thanks for your help.